# L'Hopital, $g(n)=n^a$ and $f(n)= n^b$

Tags: calculus

$g(n)=n^a$,  $f(n)=n^b$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that:
$0 \lt a \lt b$.

I want to use L'Hopital's technique to prove that $g(n)$ belongs to $f(n)$.

My attempt:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{n^{a+1}}.$$

I'm using $a+1$ to state that $b \gt a$.

The problem is that I don't know if using $a+1$ is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "belongs to f(n)"?  Using a+1 is incorrect.  You don't need l'Hôpital, just properties of exponents.

Comment: By belongs I mean Cf(n) is an upper bound of g(n) for some constant C>0.

Comment: In other words, you want to show that $g(x) = O(f(x))$.

Comment: @PEV Yes! thats what I want to prove

Comment: No, you cannot assume that $b\geq a+1$ just from assuming that $b\gt a$.

Comment: Many values of $C$ work. Do you have a specific $C$ that you suspect will do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\frac{n^a}{n^b}=n^{(a-b)}$ where $a-b<0$  So what is the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty $?

Comment: Why do we need to even mention limits at all?

Comment: is it infinit? ∞

Comment: @Wilbert: No, it's not.

Comment: n tends to cero